# icmp packets not able to reach the firewall despite of adding a specific rule, why?

Tags: firewalls, iptables

I am using iptables to allow the icmp traffic in/out of my host. Please find below are the entries from my firewall (linux based):-

```
[root@localhost ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-reply state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:ssh state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

When I am trying to ping the host I am getting the following error:-

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.1.3 ##192.168.1.3 is the IP of the firewall
PING 192.168.1.3 (192.168.1.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

Which rule should I add to the OUTPUT CHAIN of filter table to get this done. I don't want all traffic to go out; so I have selected DROP as the default policy for the chain

Comment: One thing you want to watch with the firewall ruleset as described above is that it looks like you have the default input policy as accept, really for firewalls the default policy should be drop

Comment: @Rory, yes I have made the changes to default input policy.

Comment: You shouldn't be blocking most ICMP packets at all.  See http://serverfault.com/questions/84963/why-not-block-icmp

Answer (score 1):

You have the rules backwards. In INPUT you must have icmp-**reply** and in OUTPUT icmp-**request**

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/scripts/iptables-rules read #12 is this correct yzT?

Comment: yep, #12 and #13 are ok.